# Magento 2 Merge CSS only works on homepage

Tags: magento2, merge-css

I've configured Merge and Minify CSS and Javascript in Magento 2 config (Advanced > Developer). At the homepage, it does merge and minify. 
However, at all other pages, it does NOT merge CSS. (minify css and minify+merge js is performed correctly) I can't figure out why.

Does anyone have an idea what it might be?

Magento ver 2.1.9

Comment: i am having the same issue,in my case css are not merged at home page and on all other pages it is working.If you have found any solutions please update here also

Comment: No solution yet, it's probably a bug in the theme which causes this...